# C++ Send a file containing \0 via sockets without accidental closure

Tags: c++, file, sockets

I serialize the file via the code beneath, and send it over winsocks, this works fine with textfiles, but when I tried to send a jpg, the string contains \0 as some of the character elements, so the sockets only send part of the string, thinking \0 is the end, i was considering replacing \0 with something else, but say i replace it with 'xx', then replace it back on the other end, what if the file had natural occurrences of 'xx' that get lost? Sure I could make a large, unlikely sequence, but that bloats the file.

Any help appreciated.

```
char* read_file(string path, int& len)
{
    std::ifstream infile(path);

    infile.seekg(0, infile.end);
    size_t length = infile.tellg();
    infile.seekg(0, infile.beg);
    len = length;
    char* buffer = new char[len]();

    infile.read(buffer, length);
    return buffer;
}

string load_to_buffer(string file)
{
    char* img;
    int ln;
    img = read_file(file, ln);
    string s = "";
    for (int i = 1; i <= ln; i++){
        char c = *(img + i);
        s += c;
    }
    return s;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably somewhere in your code (that isn't seen in the code you have posted) you use `strlen()` or `std::string::length()` to send the data, and/or you use `std::string::c_str()` to get the buffer. This results in truncated data because these functions stop at \0.

std::string is not good to handle binary data. Use `std::vector<char>` instead, and remove the new[] stuff.

Comment: perfect, but then what do I use as a terminating sequence to know when the packet is sent

Comment: It's two things, one to ensure that all bytes have been sent from the server, and one to acknowledge the received bytes frorm the client.

For the first, you loop the send() function to ensure that all bytes have been send (loop is necessary because send() might not send all the bytes at once). For the second, you preface your sending buffer with the expected size-to-send bytes.

Comment: "*std::string is not good to handle binary data*" - not true. `std::string` handles binary data just fine. It doesn't care about embedded null characters, and happily carries them if told to. It is only when you treat binary data as if it were a null-terminated string that things go bad. `std::string` itself does not do that, but code that *misuses* `std::string` may.

Comment: I didn't day that std::string does not handle binary data well, I said that is not good to handle (for the programmer) binary data, just because it's too easy to misuse c_str() and length() instead of data() and size().